# HowTo: Install Nvidia graphic Driver for Ubuntu 16.04 - Login loop (RTX2060)

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I bought a new HP Notebook with an NVIDIA RTX2060 graphics card and I would like to install the proprietary graphics driver. I cannot install it from Additional Drivers,  because it does not find any available drivers.

So I installed it with the .run file from NVIDIA (version 430). I did the Installation in tty1.

After the installation, I cannot login. Ubuntu asks me for my password in a loop. After I enter my password, a black screen appears and then I it asks me to enter it again.

What can I do?